# Simulate Location only in Simulator

Tags: xcode, location, device, simulate

In order to test my app, I need to turn on "Simulate Location"

As a result, the location is simulated in both the Simulator as well as on the device.

If I unplug the device while my app is being debugged, the simulated location remains my location, systemwide.

I then have to restart my device to reset to my real physical location. At least, that is what I think. Switching off and on Location Services doesn't help.

(This resetting normally happens when I'm driving my car, puzzled by the fact that Maps tells me I have to drive several hours to a location that is actually around the corner)

So, my basic question is:

Can I switch on "Simulate Location" for just the iPhone Simulator, and not for the device (my device is pretty able to know where it is anyway).

If this is not possible, is there a way to tell my iPhone to behave, without resetting the device?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It seems to me that the location should never be simulated on an actual device, but that's the behavior if you have a default location set.